# libpng containing a security vulnerability Warning iam using ADT

Tags: android

[image]

I am using buildbox and ADT bundle

I have a question about the warning that I received yesterday in google play developer console,

how to solve please help me

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me in Buildbox I search alot but there is nothing help me, as I found in some forums the Buildbox not include libpng, Admin said wait new update and all apps you are publish or update will not affected unitl Sep 17, 2016 after that you can't publish or update anything so there is no way just wait update.